# Why my ForEach Loop doesn't work in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Why nothing prints out with this code :

```
$xml=[xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<catalogue>
  <products>
    <product id="pdt1">
      <metas>
      </metas>
    </product>
    <product id="pdt2">
      <metas date="2015.07.24">
        <meta code="123456" value="abcdef" />
        <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl" />
        <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr" />
      </metas>
    </product>
  </products>
</catalogue>
'@

$product_id = "pdt2"
$metas = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//catalogue/products/product[@id='$product_id']/metas")
Foreach ($meta in $metas) {

    Write-Host $meta.code
    Write-Host $meta.value

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
Foreach ($meta in $metas) {
```

to this:

```
Foreach ($meta in $metas.meta) {
```

Comment: Beat me to it. My solution was use `$xml.SelectNodes("//catalogue/products/product[@id='$product_id']/metas/meta")`.

Comment: Post that. It's enough different, and it's worth having both options.